# Limit audio duration when played

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to build an iOS application using Swift 4 that would play different sounds. Part of what I need to do is to limit the duration of the sound file played depending on some settings.

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to set the duration of the sound prior to playing it so it can stop after the set duration. If so, how?

I'm currently using Swift's *AVAudioPlayer* but I don't know if it can do it. My current code is shown below:

```
// resName set depending on settings

url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resName, withExtension: "mp3")

do{
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
} catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.debugDescription)
}

audioPlayer.play()
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Please post code of what you've tried so far. If you need further help on [how to ask take a look at this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi! @creyD Thanks for the suggestion, I added a short snippet of my code :)

Comment: @Grey how did you end up solving it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ sorry for the late reply, but your suggestion worked so I guessed it's good :D I'll need to test it more but I'll accept your answer for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you are in control of playing the sounds, one way how to deal with it would be running a `Timer` when you start playing that would after the given time period stop playing:

```
let timeLimit = 1.6 // get it from settings
player.play()
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeLimit, repeats: false) { (timer) in
    player.stop()
}
```

And in case you need to cancel it, you can keep a reference to the `timer` and cancel it using `timer.invalidate()`.

Comment: I see, this looks nice. Would this still work nicely even if I have to play a lot of sounds consecutively?

Comment: well.. I guess you'll have to try it to know.. you can use recursion in the `timer`'s block to restart playing with new sound once the timer finished.. if you keep the reference to the `timer`, then you can cancel it anytime.. I don't see a reason why that should not work..

Answer (score -1):

As an audio engineer, I recommend editing your audio to be exactly how you want it to avoid any unwanted artifacts that can happen from coding.